# CSS Layout Mainbody not appearing

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am still trying to mess around with this layout stuff and just when I thought I understood it, I can't seem to get this div to show.

I have a simple nav and footer and a main and the main is not showing. It's supposed to have black background but it's not appearing. Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/44655gw4/2/

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}




body{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #527a7a;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 19px;
}


* {

margin: 0;

}

#pagewrap {

min-height: 100%;
margin-bottom: -174px;
width: 80%;

}

#pagewrap:after {

content: "";
display: block;

}

#footer, #pagewrap:after {

height: 174px;

}




.sub:last-child {
    border: 0px;
}

#footer {
background-color:  #999999;
clear: both;

}

.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.sub {
    padding: 12px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #999999;
    color: white;
    border-right: solid white 1px;  
}


.sub:last-child {

    border: 0px;
}




#nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
  padding-right: 20px;
  height: calc(100vh - 174px);
  float: left;


}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
}
#nav li {
  margin: 0px;

}
#nav li a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;

}
#nav li a:hover {
  color:  white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px white;
}

#content {

    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
  float: right;
  background-color: black;


}

<body>
<div id="pagewrap">

        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

            </ul>




        </div>

    <div id="content"></div>








    </div>







<!--
<footer id="footer">

</footer>

-->
<hr>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum </div>
        <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by main? you mean main content ?

Comment: @dazunE yes sir. I edited my post. The black background box with the id of 'content' should be there but it's not for some reason.

Comment: where is you main body?? u didn't does anything in the main part.

Comment: The Page Wrap is the part that contains everything except for the footer. 

I can add the body tags if you want, but the first thing after the body tag is the pagewrap. So nav is inside pagewrap and content is in pagewrap as well and I want to get the content part to be aside the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

For the #content add

```
#content {
    width: 82%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and for #nav add

```
#nav { float;left;}
```

Here is the complete markup

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}




body{
 height: 100%;
 
 margin: 0;
 font-family: courier;
 font-size: 19px;
}


* {

margin: 0;

}

#pagewrap {

min-height: 100%;
margin-bottom: -174px;

}

#pagewrap:after {

content: "";
display: block;

}

#footer, #pagewrap:after {

height: 174px;

}




.sub:last-child {
    border: 0px;
}

#footer {
background-color:  #00e600;    clear: left;
}

.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.sub {
    padding: 12px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #00e600;
    color: white;
    border-right: solid white 1px;  
}


.sub:last-child {

 border: 0px;
}




#nav {
  height: calc(100vh - 174px);
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: brown;
  float:left;
  padding-right: 20px;

}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: brown;
}
#nav li {
  margin: 0px;

}
#nav li a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: pink;
  background-color: brown;

}
#nav li a:hover {
  color:  white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px white;
}

#content {
        width: 82%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagewrap">

        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

            </ul>




        </div>

    <div id="content">
      
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


    </div>








    </div>







<!--
<footer id="footer">

</footer>

-->
<hr>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum </div>
        <div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum </div>
    </div>
</div>
```